# Creating a date table for multiple primary keys between a specified open and close date for each primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop

Good day,

I have been wracking my brain for the past few hours to build a table that looks like this:

[image]

I have about 33 000 entries that have their own opening and closing dates. I am trying to build a table that puts each of the dates (including the opening and closing dates) in a single row per entry (JOURNAL_NO) below each other in SQL Server Management Studio.

I need to run a check on each day for each entry and I have tried to build the table by making use of my primary table and a calendar table that I created. Please refer to the code below (I have also included the calendar code below this):

Code I'm trying to get working:

```
DECLARE @START_DATE date = '2014-01-01',
        @END_DATE date = '2018-12-31'
WHILE @START_DATE <= @END_DATE
BEGIN
    SET @START_DATE = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N) - 1, @START_DATE)

    SELECT LO_MASTER.JOURAL_NO, --(33000 entries)
            LO_MASTER.START_DATE, -- each entry has a different opening date 
            CAL.DATE -- date in calendar table
            CAL.DAY AS DATEPART(DAY,[DATE]),
            CAL.MONTH AS DATEPART(MONTH,[DATE]),
            CAL.YEAR AS DATEPART(YEAR,[DATE]), -- these will be the date parts between the OPEN_DATE & CLOSE_DATE for each account
            LO_MASTER.END_DATE -- each entry has a different closing date
    FROM [dbo.][F1_master] as LO_MASTER
         inner join CALENDAR_TABLE as CAL LO_MASTER.DATE = CAL.DATE
    WHERE CAL.DATE between LO_MASTER.START_DATE and LO_MASTER.END_DATE -- range where the fields from table b need to be populated for each account

END
```

Table definition:

```
USE [master]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[dummy_data]    Script Date: 11/02/2019 07:31:59 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dummy_data](
    [JOURNAL_NO] [int] NULL,
    [START_DATE] [date] NULL,
    [END_DATE] [date] NULL,
    [DURATION_ON_BOOK] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Sample data:

```
JOURNAL_NO  START_DATE  END_DATE    DURATION_ON_BOOK
101388  15/01/2014  01/01/2017  35
101499  14/01/2014  21/01/2017  36
101502  17/01/2014  17/02/2017  53
101876  06/01/2014  30/09/2017  35
101877  06/01/2014  24/01/2018  60
101878  07/01/2014  28/02/2018  60
101879  07/01/2014  19/01/2017  50
101881  07/01/2014  16/04/2018  58
101882  07/01/2014  13/11/2018  58
101883  08/01/2014  17/11/2016  59
101884  13/01/2014  26/06/2018  60
101886  13/01/2014  20/12/2016  59
101887  13/01/2014  13/12/2016  60
101888  13/01/2014  11/09/2017  43
101889  14/01/2014  07/12/2017  68
101890  14/01/2014  02/01/2018  58
101892  15/01/2014  21/02/2017  38
101893  17/01/2014  15/09/2017  64
101894  21/01/2014  02/02/2017  40
101896  21/01/2014  09/05/2016  38
101904  27/01/2014  21/12/2016  69
101906  27/01/2014  11/11/2016  36
101966  07/01/2014  10/03/2017  36
101967  07/01/2014  09/07/2018  40
102073  07/01/2014  15/09/2016  60
102074  13/01/2014  20/06/2017  40
102076  14/01/2014  15/06/2016  40
102077  15/01/2014  01/12/2016  60
102079  17/01/2014  12/10/2016  40
102081  21/01/2014  20/04/2017  40
102082  23/01/2014  14/02/2017  38
102234  02/01/2014  20/09/2017  46
102236  08/01/2014  05/05/2017  36
102237  15/01/2014  23/08/2017  68
102240  21/01/2014  27/02/2018  50
102241  21/01/2014  25/08/2016  37
102253  06/01/2014  26/10/2016  27
102254  07/01/2014  17/11/2016  61
102255  07/01/2014  26/04/2017  38
102256  10/01/2014  11/10/2017  42
102258  13/01/2014  18/05/2017  26
102263  17/01/2014  29/11/2018  74
102265  20/01/2014  31/10/2016  31
102372  06/01/2014  25/04/2017  35
102463  09/01/2014  25/08/2017  69
102464  09/01/2014  01/07/2016  26
102465  15/01/2014  24/12/2016  36
102530  06/01/2014  24/12/2017  48
102531  07/01/2014  28/08/2017  76
102532  09/01/2014  21/06/2017  39
```

Could anyone please assist me? I haven't been coding that long and my troubleshoot attempts aren't providing any correct solutions. It would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You definitely do not want or need a loop here. Your "calendar" table is actually a tally table. This is what you want to use. Also, don't use that antiquated join syntax. You should use the ANSI-92 style joins, they have been around for more than 25 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins And aliases should have some meaning instead of a,b,c https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3

Comment: OK. Let's go with just a couple journals here (101388 and 101499) What is the expected output? You want every day between january 15, 2014 and january 1, 2017 for 101388?

Comment: Yes exactly that. I want to have the journal number static and the days changing in each row between the start_date and end_date. After that journal has all the entries in the table, I would like it to move over to the next journal and repeat the process. Thank you for the inline edits. My internet connection is up and down constantly due to severe thunderstorms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a tally table this is pretty simple. I keep one on my system as a view that is lightning fast because it doesn't need any disc I/O at all. It look amazingly similar to what you had posted initially.

```
create View [dbo].[cteTally] as

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
select N from cteTally
GO
```

Next we need some sample data. I stripped this down to just a couple of journals to demonstrate.

```
declare @dummy_data table
(
    JOURNAL_NO int
    , START_DATE datetime
    , END_DATE datetime
    , DURATION_ON_BOOK int
)

insert @dummy_data values
(101388, '20140115', '20170101', 35)
, (101499, '20160114', '20170121', 36)
```

Now we just need to leverage the power of a tally table with your data. This is what your query might look like. No need for loops, just some basic date math.

```
select *
    , EachDay = dateadd(day, t.N - 1, d.Start_Date)
    , MyDay = t.N
    , MyMonth = datediff(month, d.Start_DATE, dateadd(day, t.N - 1, d.Start_Date)) + 1
    , MyYear = datepart(year, dateadd(day, t.N - 1, d.Start_Date))
from @dummy_data d
join cteTally t on t.N <= datediff(day, d.START_DATE, d.END_DATE) + 1
```

Comment: Wow! You really are a master Sean. Thank you for the detailed explanation and talking me through the logic that I don't need to use a loop. Really appreciate the assistance sir! P.S. would there be any other blogs you could recommend that I can improve my coding?

Comment: You might check out sql server central.com. Lots of great articles and totally focused on sql server.